# WP woocommerce Функция которая возвращает саму себя через apply_filters

Tags: php, wordpress

Помогите пожалуйста в логике.
Есть стандартная функция

```
function wc_price( $price, $args = array() ) {
extract( apply_filters( 'wc_price_args', wp_parse_args( $args, array(
    'ex_tax_label'       => false,
    'currency'           => '',
    'decimal_separator'  => wc_get_price_decimal_separator(),
    'thousand_separator' => wc_get_price_thousand_separator(),
    'decimals'           => wc_get_price_decimals(),
    'price_format'       => get_woocommerce_price_format(),
) ) ) );
$unformatted_price = $price;
$negative          = $price < 0;
$price             = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
$price             = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', number_format( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator ), $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $decimals > 0 ) {
    $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );
}
$formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ) . '</span>', $price );
$return          = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';
if ( $ex_tax_label && wc_tax_enabled() ) {
    $return .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
}
/**
 * Filters the string of price markup.
 *
 * @param string $return            Price HTML markup.
 * @param string $price             Formatted price.
 * @param array  $args              Pass on the args.
 * @param float  $unformatted_price Price as float to allow plugins custom formatting. Since 3.2.0.
 */
return apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args, $unformatted_price );
```

}

и возвращает она себя же через
return apply_filters( 'wc_price', $return, $price, $args );
 , почему это не бесконечный цикл?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что фильтр и функция - разные сущности, хотя и имеют одинаковое имя. Для того, чтобы был бесконечный цикл, надо добавить фильтр, который ссылается на саму функцию, примерно так:

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'wc_price', 10, 2 );
```

Но этого в коде нет. Более того, вообще в коде WooCommerce не определен по умолчанию фильтр 'wc_price'. Это значит, что если пользователь не установит свой фильтр в теме или плагине, то последняя строчка в приведенном вами коде вернет значение переменной $return.

Фильтр в WordPress - всего лишь текстовая строка, имя. К этому имени могут быть прикреплены разные функции фильтров, которые исполняются ядром в порядке их приоритета. Если вызвана apply_filters() с первым параметром, к которому ничего не прикреплено, ядро вернет в качестве результата второй параметр. В вашем случае - переменную $return.